# Handling enums in post request body

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, enums

I am creating an ASP.NET Core Web API.

I want a post body like:

```
{
"Name": "XYX",
"Status":"Waiting"
}
```

Status is an Enum:

```
public enum Status
{
    [Description("Waiting")]
    Waiting = 1,
    [Description("Occuring")]
    Occuring = 2,
    [Description("Stopping")]
    Stopping = 3,
}
```

What should I do so I that I don't get the error:

```
The JSON value could not be converted to PostgreSql.Enums.StatusEnum. Path:
```

P.S.: Tried what's mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58319534/post-request-that-includes-a-enum-description) but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Try using `System.Text.Json` attributes: [JsonStringEnumConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonstringenumconverter?view=netcore-3.1) and [JsonConverterAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverterattribute?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Aslo please add your model/json parsing code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a string to an enum in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @GuruStron I tried  `[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]` and it worked well for me.

Comment: Will add as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ASP.NET in .NET Core 3.0 [removed](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/SystemTextJsonAndNewBuiltinJSONSupportInNETCore.aspx) the JSON.NET(Newtonsoft.Json) dependency (it is used in the link you've provided), so try using `System.Text.Json`'s attributes: [`JsonStringEnumConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonstringenumconverter?view=netcore-3.1) and [`JsonConverterAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverterattribute?view=netcore-3.1).

**UPD**
Was not able to reproduce the issue you mentioned in the comment:

```
class MyClass
{    
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
    public Status MyProperty { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
    public Status MyProperty1 { get; set; }
}

var serialized = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new MyClass
{
    MyProperty = Status.Waiting,
    MyProperty1 = Status.Occuring
}); // results in string containing {"MyProperty":"Waiting","MyProperty1":"Occuring"}

var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(serialized); // all properties set
```

Also please note that name of the `Status` value is used for serialization/deserialization not the value of `Description` attribute.

Comment: I see that it worked in the case mentioned in my question, but strangely isn't working for another similar parameter I'm trying to add. What could be the reason?

Comment: **EDIT:** For `Description("Waiting")]  Waiting = 1,` the post body is taking "waiting" for one param and 1 for another, why is that?

Comment: @Mansi It is not enough information, please add the class and json.

Answer (score 4):

You can create an enum as follows:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public enum Status : byte
{
    Waiting = 1,
    Occuring = 2,
    Stopping = 3
}
```

& pass string value in POST body

Answer (score 2):

You can add following code in your Statup.cs/Program.cs to set it globally for the project.

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x =>{
// serialize enums as strings in api responses (e.g. Role)
x.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());});
```

Answer (score 2):

For record (which in C# is a class or struct that provides special syntax and behavior for working with data models) and it's fields it is necessary to add **[property: JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]**
like below in the code:

```
internal record ShipmentBookingStatusModel
(
    int ShipmentId
    , string OtmShipmentId
    , [property: JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))] OtmBookingStatusEnum BookingStatus
){ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason your post body is being passed the description as opposed to the enum value? If this is enum is part of the API scheme/definition then anything that consumes should know about it too therefore the API could be called with the integer value like:

```
{
"Name": "XYX",
"Status":1
}
```

I know its not an exact solution to what you asked but it's an alternative and may be worth thinking about?

Answer (score 0):

Since .Net 8 you may specify **JsonStringEnumConverter<TEnum>**.
It's compatible with native AOT.

```
public class MyDto
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter<Status>))]
    public Status Status {get; init;}
}
```

Or record implementation:

```
public record MyDto(
    [property:JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter<Status>))]
    Status Status
);
```